# How do I create a popup for windows form settings

Tags: c#

I need to create a popup in a windows form. For example if an user tries to change anything in the windows form settings they should get a popup dialogue. In the form there are five toolbar buttons. If the user jumps into another toolbar and tries to save changes they should get a popup dialogue.

Comment: When asking a question on stackoverflow, you're supposed to show the code you've created in order for us to help you. We are not going to just write stuff for you, that is not how this website works. Please go over to the help center and read up on how to ask questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Its not real clear what your trying to do..you talk about pop up form then give example of a dialogue..then you talk about toolbars. Look over your question again and describe clearly what your trying to do.. ie When user is looking over a record on a form they cannot edit it...if they try to click on a field a dialogue box should popup and warn them. As Glubus says you should show code

Answer (score -1):

May you design a new form and use the `ShowDialog()` method. It will open the form as a modal window. You will not be able to focus something different until this window is closed. The advantage is that you're able to design this "Pop-up" by yourself.

If you want to show something like a short message, a `MessageBox.Show()` will do your job! For more information about MessageBoxes you better read the official [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx), especially the parts concerning the `Show()` method and it's overloads.

Answer (score -2):

Use this
MessageBox.Show("Error message",
    "Title of error");